# How to simultaneously train two neural networks to minimize the difference between their outputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

For each event/sample, I have a set of values x1,x2,y1,y2,z,k. I have 2 neural networks that I want to undergo two phases of training. The first neural network takes x1,x2 as inputs and outputs z. The second neural network takes y1,y2 as inputs and outputs k.

First phase:
Separately train the first neural network with inputs x1,x2 to output z and the second neural network with inputs y1,y2 to output k.

Second phase:
Here I’m ready to let go of z and k, and I’m looking for a value h that is somewhere between z and k. Therefore, for this phase, I want to train both neural networks to minimize the difference between their outputs (i.e. for each epoch, train NN1 on the output of NN2, and train NN2 on the output of NN1. Update the weights and biases of each. Then, use the new weights and biases to calculate a new output for each. Then, go through another epoch to train NN1 on the new output of NN2, and train NN2 on the new output of NN1)

What Machine Learning package allows me to do that. I’m familiar with Keras (with a TensorFlow backend). Is that possible in Keras? If not, is it possible in TensorFlow?

Thanks

Comment: That is already possible with TensorFlow, likely with Keras too. But what have you tried? We cannot tell which issues might have emerged from your own attempt at this.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have both models as `model1` and `model2`.

Let's create a layer that calculates the difference between their outputs:

```py
from keras.layers import Lambda

difference = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] - x[1])([model1.output, model2.output])
```

Then, let's make a model that outputs the difference.

```py
#if your models have one input each, (if x1 and x2 are elements in the input array)
diffModel = Model([model1.input, model2.input], difference)

#if your models have two inputs (if x1 and x2 are two input tensors)    
diffModel = Model(model1.inputs + model2.inputs, difference)
```

Let's compile this model, choose a loss to compare the difference with 0:

```py
diffModel.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='mse')
```

And let's train it with zero as output:

```py
#if models with one input:
diffModel.fit([x,y], np.zeros(shape))

#if models with two inputs:
diffModel.fit([x1,x2,y1,y2], np.zeros(shape))
```